# how do i make links clickable in QtWebView?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm in the process of writing a web browser with QtWebView, i tested it using an html page but it turns out the links are not working. What do i do?

Comment: What does 'not working' really mean? You really need to put more detail into your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should set a "link delegation policy" for WebView's page, because it defaults to "DontDelegateLinks".

Try:

```
webView.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
```

And connect page's `link_clicked()` signal to appropriate slot.

Look at:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#page

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html#linkDelegationPolicy-prop

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html#LinkDelegationPolicy-enum